# When embedding a controller call inside a twig in Drupal, I get "Unknown "controller" function"

Tags: php, templates, drupal, controller, twig

I'm inside a twig, and trying to embed a controller call using render(controller()) and it's not finding "controller".

Here's a short exerpt:

```
{{ render(controller('\\Controller\\ContractPageController::get_contract_files',{ 'get_contract_files': node.title.value }  )) }}
```

```
Here's the entire error messsage:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "controller" function. in Twig\ExpressionParser->getFunctionNodeClass() (line 309 of themes/custom/dir_bootstrap/templates/content/node--contract.html.twig).
Twig\ExpressionParser->getFunctionNode() (Line: 235)
Twig\ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression() (Line: 175)
Twig\ExpressionParser->getPrimary() (Line: 70)
Twig\ExpressionParser->parseExpression() (Line: 607)
Twig\ExpressionParser->parseArguments() (Line: 459)
Twig\ExpressionParser->getFunctionNode() (Line: 235)
Twig\ExpressionParser->parsePrimaryExpression() (Line: 175)
Twig\ExpressionParser->getPrimary() (Line: 70)
Twig\ExpressionParser->parseExpression() (Line: 141)
Twig\Parser->subparse() (Line: 97)
Twig\Parser->parse() (Line: 562)
Twig\Environment->parse() (Line: 594)
Twig\Environment->compileSource() (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->compileSource() (Line: 408)
Twig\Environment->loadClass() (Line: 381)
Twig\Environment->loadTemplate() (Line: 55)
twig_render_template() (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 433)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 204)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 242)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 580)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 243)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->prepare() (Line: 132)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse() (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray()
call_user_func() (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 174)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 707)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)
```

I've tried just using an include to another twig, but basically I'm new at this and need to call the controller directly in this one page.